# string matching not working in js?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

when i tried to check my Ajax response with string then its always printing fail case.

Here is my ajax part

```
var username =  document.getElementById("name").value;
var password =  document.getElementById("password").value;
var dataString = 'email='+ username + '&password='+ password;


$.ajax({
   url:"http://test.com/login.php",
  type: "post",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
  alert(data);
      var test = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
      alert(test); //working
      if(test == "1"){   //condition failed
          alert("h");
      }else{
          alert("fail");  //printing this
      }
  },
  error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
  }
});
```

alert [image]

Comment: My guess would be that `test` isn't equal to `"1"`. Your code/comments seem to confirm that.

Comment: its 1 ..i can see that in alert

Comment: it may be `1`, but it isn't `"1"`. note that `1` likely has some hidden characters that aren't showing up in the alert.

Comment: Have you considered debugging this with the console rather than alerts? the console can show you a raw view of the response in the network tab.

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: I think it is an integer...

Comment: @Mikey since he's using `==`, it wouldn't matter if it were an integer. but... it's probably a string.

Comment: @KevinB Yep, you are right. Time for bed, lol

Comment: did you try print the type of test data: console.log(typeof test);

Comment: testing that part now

Comment: `alert(encodeURIComponent(test));`

Comment: what I am guessing is that test is a string like "1 ", there are whitespace inside

Comment: its a string...in console it showing string

Comment: try to get the string length

Comment: fixed it ... error was in my regx  it should be like this data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");   instead of   data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");

Comment: by mistake am adding a white space while removing new line charactor

Comment: @KelvinYe you can write it as answer ..i willl accept

Comment: @Bangalore, thanks for the score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I am guessing is that test is a string like "1 ", there are whitespace inside

```js
data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); 
// instead of data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ")
```